# Cannot edit / edit queue

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Can someone explain to me what this means?

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.

Comment: the warning itself is ambiguous, it should state clearly its meaning not `7 days` when after 2 days it still says `7 days`

Comment: You should probably create a new question tagged 'feature-request' about improving the message.

Comment: It means that too many of your edits were rejected, and you won't be able to suggest a new one for seven days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems rather straightforward. You've had 9 edit suggestions rejected. High rep users reviewing edit suggestions takes time, so the system temporarily stops accepting suggestions from people with a pattern of rejections. You should look into why those suggestions were rejected so you can hopefully stop making the same mistakes in the future

From the [proposed FAQ post about edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work):

> #### What about abuse?
>
> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.

Comment: so if reach that limit, there's no way that i can get it back?

Comment: @ianace Well, not for 7 days; then you should be fine

Comment: well it isnt that intuitive enough, if a day has passed then it should state `6 days` not the static initial `7 days`

Comment: I assume that as well as quality control, this prevents all the posts being turned into ads for WizzoSuperMatic BellyFluffExtractor TM

Comment: "You should look into why those suggestions were rejected so you can hopefully stop making the same mistakes in the future";
Where can I see my suggested edits?

Comment: @ValentinoRu http://stackoverflow.com/users/1339620/valentino-ru?tab=activity&sort=suggestions