# "edit queue is full" page returns 200 OK, and is not HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error, http

I got an error message on the site: "`Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes`", but that was the entire text of the page. Even though the Content-Type header I received was "`text/html; charset=utf-8`", the page was plain text with no HTML formatting. I don't mind that it was in plain text (actually I kinda liked it), but then the Content-Type should be "`text/plain`".

Also, the HTTP response code received was "200 OK".

This is bad! Because everything was not okay.

It was an error and should have a more appropriate HTTP response code.

Comment: Agreed, it should be `503`

Comment: this has been posted before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88086/cannot-edit-edit-queue

Comment: different questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the next build we'll properly return a 503 status when this case (or [this other case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88086/cannot-edit-edit-queue)) happen.