# "The edit queue is full" message is not been shown on an edit page

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, error-message

**Environment:**
Vivaldi 3.3 / Chrome 85.

**Preconditions:**

1. User account without the [edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege;
2. The edit queue is almost full.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Click on Edit link of any post;
2. Make your changes;
3. Click on <kbd>Save edits</kbd> button when the edit queue is full.

**Actual Results:**

1. Nothing happens visually, it just doesn't work;
2. If you look at the Network tab of DevTools, the server responds with `200 OK` ([which apparently it shouldn't do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95356/578924)) and the following JSON:
   [image: "Save edits" response]

**Expected Result:**
Popup message appears:
[image: The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!]

---

I've noticed this for the first time around Dec 2020 on Stack Overflow when the queues were almost always full and it happened to me again on Super User yesterday.

Comment: I would personally like [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356300/578924) to be implemented instead.

Comment: @Rob I've seen that post, but how does it related? I think I've made it absolutely clear that I'm reporting a **bug** first of all: the message above does NOT display for me and I think it can be very confusing for new users.

Comment: To all and @Rob: This is a **bug report**, not a feature request! Clarification on a suggestion linked above: it's not very user-friendly to say that the queue is full when someone already made changes and about to post them, I'm not talking about increasing a general limit.

Comment: I can confirm that I've run into this on multiple occasions recently too, over on SO. I thought this bug had already been reported, but I don't have a link handy.